# Route thru points

Tags: google-maps, kml

How i can get kml file from Google Maps that contains route thru several points. Now i use this link `http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=51.591016,-0.107382&daddr=51.359619,-0.147695&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml` It work, but only for two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know that Google Maps and Google earth have different capabilities for displaying kml files.  Google Earth has almost no limitations, you can author full mxd's to google earth with legends and everything, google maps, however, does not have nearly the same capability.

In google maps you are restricted to displaying 200 kml points on one page, this is because this application is server based and created using javascript, for performance purposes, you are limited to only 200 kml points per page.  You might notice that the rest of your points are on different pages, unfortunatly you cannot view them all at the same time.  One thing that you can do, Is serve up a url to your kml file (you can do this easily if you have an ftp account or with google my pages), then just enter the url into the search box, presto! all of your points will show up, only, you will not be able to route directions or edit any attributes, you can merely save to my maps and share the display of the points (again people will not be able to get directions from the points)

Serving up your kml to a url address is good practise, it will save you time, also you can use your own symbology, if you enter the url address in the upload area (as opposed to the search box) you will be able to keep your symbology, edit the attributes and get directions and all of that other fun stuff. You will however have the limitation of only being able to display 200 points per page.

Thus if you need to be able to have the user search for directions from your points, you can only have 200 points at a time :(
enter the url in the search box and all of your points will appear......but no directions..

Hope this helps.
For Reference:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/kml.htm

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html